# Best way in Java to hide public setters from client applications

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Spring Application which is built on top of DynamoDB. I am trying to write a `saveFoo()` Repository method that will save an object of type `Foo` to the database. This method will be called from the application layer.

What I'm struggling with is that the `Foo` class has fields within it that are Dynamo specific. I don't want clients of the `saveFoo()` class to think they need to create an object of type `Foo` with these fields. Nor do I want them to attempt to ever set these values themselves.

These database-specific fields need public getters and setters in order to work with the DynamoDB SDK.

The database model class looks like the following:

```java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "foo")
public class Foo {
  // Fields the client should be setting
  private String bar;
  private String baz;

  // Fields the client should not access and should not care about. They are internal fields used for DynamoDB purposes. 
  private Long version;
  private String gsiIndexKey;

  // Empty constructor needed for deserialization of data from dynamodb
  public Foo() {
  }

  // Getters and setters for all of the above fields.
}
```

And the repository method to save the object to the DB:

```java
public class FooRepositoryImpl {
  public Foo saveFoo(WhatClassShouldThisBe foo) {
    // Code that saves a new Foo item to the database and returns it.
  }
}
```

My current idea is to create a FooWrapper interface that the `saveFoo()` method can take as a parameter. The wrapper will allow the client to set the fields that they should have control over, but does not expose fields related to the database internals. Something like the below:

```java
/**
* Allows us restrict visibility of the Foo fields to the Application by hiding database internal fields.
**/
public interface FooWrapper {
  Foo getFoo()
}

public class FooWrapperImpl implements FooWrapper {
  private final Foo foo;
  
  public FooWrapperImpl(String bar, String baz) {
    foo = new Foo();
    foo.setBar(bar);
    foo.setBaz(baz);
  }
  
  @Override
  public Foo getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }
}

public class FooRepositoryImpl {
  public Foo saveFoo(FooWrapper fooWrapper) {
    Foo foo = fooWrapper.getFoo(); // Save this item to db
    // Code that saves a new Foo item to the database and returns it.
  }
}
```

What are your thoughts on this approach? Does anyone know of some better techniques I could try? I can't help but feel that I am over-engineering things here.

Comment: Are you doing your own Object->Item mapping?  It's not clear why you think the "internal" fields in `Foo` might not be of interest to some client software.  They are legitimate attributes of a `Foo`, no?  I'm sensing an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)
here.

Comment: I don't know anything about DynamoDB but the first thing that occurs to me when someone says they don't want clients messing with an object is to make that object immutable.  Consider a builder pattern for creation if the object is complex.

Comment: @JimGarrison - The internal fields are not legitimate attributes of a Foo outside of the context of dynamoDB. They are used for Dynamo specific purposes. In this case, `version` allows for optimistic locking and `gsiIndexKey` is used for populating a special index.

Comment: @markspace I've considered the builder pattern as well. I can add a builder to Foo() that only allows for setting the fields I care about. Unfortunately, I cannot go fully immutable due to other restrictions in my application (another topic...). Since the `Foo` class needs an empty constructor for the Dynamo SDK I felt like this wasn't enough.

Comment: Then if a builder pattern isn't appropriate, defining the public view as an interface seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Or possibly look at the DTO/DAO pattern, and make the object that DynamoDB works with different that the object your model works with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose only an interface to clients that has the methods you want. Internally you can call the other public methods of the implementation, but the client code won't know them.

If you are using modern Java, don't export your implementation classes outside of your module.  Only export the public interface.

You could also keep an interface for internal use that has more methods than the public API.

```
public interface Foo {
    public void setBar(String bar);
    public void setBaz(String baz);
}
```

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "foo")
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
  // Fields the client should be setting
  private String bar;
  private String baz;

  // Fields the client should not access and should not care about. They are internal fields used for DynamoDB purposes. 
  private Long version;
  private String gsiIndexKey;

  // Empty constructor needed for deserialization of data from dynamodb
  public FooImpl() {
  }

  // Getters and setters for all of the above fields.
  @Override
  public void setBar(String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  @Override
  public void setBaz(String baz) {
    this.baz = bar;
  }

  // Not part of the Foo interface
  public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
  }

  public void setGsiIndexKey(String indexKey) {
    this.gsiIndexKey = indexKey;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I was on the right track but failed to recognize that my existing class could implement the interface itself.